# Exclude specific URL from HTTPS redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, typo3

I'm using the following TYPO3 mod-rewrite configuration (cleaned from not working attempts).

- I want to exclude a specific URL from getting redirected to https.
- Additionally add a rule for redirecting this url to http, if requested via https.

My errorcase is mostly to end up by getting redirected to index.php. Has anybody an idea?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^fileadmin/(.*/)?_recycler_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^fileadmin/templates/.*(\.txt|\.ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^typo3conf/ext/[^/]+/Resources/Private/ - [F]

    RewriteRule ^(typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Attempt (not working):

```
Action application/x-httpd-php55 /cgi-sys/php55-fcgi-starter.fcgi
AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php55

php_flag use_trans_sid Off
php_value date.timezone "Europe/Berlin"
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value memory_limit 1024M


<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </IfModule>
  FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/this_uri [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/this_uri [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^fileadmin/(.*/)?_recycler_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^fileadmin/templates/.*(\.txt|\.ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^typo3conf/ext/[^/]+/Resources/Private/ - [F]

    RewriteRule ^(typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, the following RewriteRule to index.php. The index.php was getting redirected to https each time it was requested via http.
With the following line could solve the problem.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
```

Comment: Where do i put this line ?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a spacific uri from https redirection, just put the following line above your https redirection Rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/this_uri [NC]
```

And to redirect this_uri to http from https :

put the following 2 lines Bellow RewriteEngine directive in your htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/this_uri [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem. `https://www.domain.de/this_uri` does not get redirected and `http://www.domain.de/this_uri` is getting redirected to `https://www.domain.de/index.php`

Comment: Can you post your current htaccess file?

Comment: There should be a space between Pattern and target **^ http** check your first rule. is that a typo?

Comment: Ok typo. But now both https and http to this_uri redirects to to index.php

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, struggled for 4 hours and finally got my specific url to redirect to http

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(home/panel/videos|user/profile) [NC] # Multiple urls
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(home/panel/videos|user/profile) [NC] # Multiple urls
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It worked for me :)